# SPFx Field Customizer - issue with loading customizer, manifest not found

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, spfx-extensions, fieldcustomizers

I implemented field customizer for list, tested it locally where it works, and then deployed to Sharepoint Online.
There I have following issue:

```
 Fail to load customizer for column: myColumn, componentId: e615f1df-8aba-4e6e-b86c-7f479dcadfea, error: Manifest not found for componentId "e615f1df-8aba-4e6e-b86c-7f479dcadfea".
```

Additional information about versions:

```
SPFX Version: 1.16.1
Node version: 16.17.1
React version: 17.0.1
Edge: Version 119.0.2151.58 (Official build) (64-bit)
```

I use custom CDN on my site, I created folder in SiteAssets where I upload

What is the solution to this?